# How can I change the setAlwaysOnTop() property of an existing JFrame window in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I have a method windowFrame() which extends Jframe and sets the GUI for my program, the instance is myFrame in the main method. As default it is set to setAlwaysOnTop(false). But within the windowFrame() method I have a JCheckBox which I want to use to turn true or false the 'always on top' property. My question is how can I do that to the already existing myFrame window GUI?

I have the listener and everything but I just don't know how to refer to the myFrame window in the main method as the JCheckBox and listener are inside the windowFrame() method but the instance is of course external to them. I tried using this.setAlwaysOnTop(true) and just setAlwaysOnTop(true), but of course that doesn't work.

Additional info: everything is wrapped in the same Main Class and I just need an instance of that Window.

Comment: Your question isn't really how to set the property. You apparently know how to do it. It's more about why your design doesn't work. This isn't really a question that can be answered, especially without seeing considerably more code than you've posted.

Comment: @dansvank I agree with Ryan, you need to include some code. Make sure you are describing the situation accurately, also. You can't extend a class with a method. I imagine that you have a class that extends JFrame, and you instantiate that class in your main method. Also, when you say you "have the listener", it's not clear what type of listener you have. There are a number of different listeners defined in the Swing widget set. As Ryan said, this may be more an issue of learning how to design using Swing. Post code and we'll try to help.

Comment: Yes well, I was thinking of some keyword like 'this' or 'super' (I know those are for other uses) that I could use to refer to the instance of the windowFrame I just realized that I could solve the problem by just declaring the variable myFrame outside the main() method so the scope is visible for the ItemListener in the windowFrame() method too... I wasted a lot of time in silly runarounds. Sorry about that hehe 

Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

- not possible with [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) without dirty hacks, don't do that
- you have to use proper Container, then you have look at [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html), method [JDialog#setAlwaysOnTop(boolean alwaysOnTop)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setAlwaysOnTop%28boolean%29)